# Bash "script" command within bash files?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have a bash script, /usr/bin/local/myscript. I run the file usually from an external software (in my case Autohotkey), basically I mean the script will be finished immediately and the window closes so I cannot see any logs on the window, info logs or error logs. So I do like to "script" the entire running steps for debugging when the program didn't work well. But simply putting a `script ~/script.txt` in the first of the `myscript` file didn't work, I don't know what is going on, the next lines on the file didn't executed basically. So, is there a (proper) way to use "script" in bash files, or better alternative to "script" for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But simply putting a `script ~/script.txt` in the first of the `myscript` file didn't work, I don't know what is going on, the next lines on the file didn't executed basically.

For a shell interpreting `myscript`, `script ~/script.txt` is just a command that runs an external executable. The executable is `script` in this case.

If the executable was `sleep`, `tar` or `ls`, you would expect the shell to wait till the executable finishes before interpreting the rest of `myscript`. With `script` it's not different: the shell waits for `script` to finish.

`script` is intended for interactive use. `script ~/script.txt` runs an interactive shell which is not the shell that interprets `myscript`. You wrote "the window closes" (when without `script`), so I assume `myscript` runs in some terminal emulator that displays a window. If so, then (with `script`) you probably saw this inner shell started by `script` and could interact with it while the outer shell was waiting. `script` logs what you do in the inner shell. Exiting the inner shell terminates `script` and only then the outer shell (i.e. `myscript`) continues. But maybe you closed the terminal emulator, the outer shell got SIGHUP and never continued.

This is not important since it should now be clear `script` called from within `myscript` cannot help you with debugging `myscript`, even if the outer shell continues.

There are at least two methods to debug `myscript`:

1. Redirect stderr of the script to a logfile. This can be done from within the script with

   ```
   # just after shebang
   exec 2>/path/to/logfile
   ```

   If `myscript` generates output on its stdout that is important and actually goes somewhere (via a pipe or redirection) then you don't want to break this. But if it normally prints to the terminal and you'd like to log this as well then redirect both stderr and stdout to the logfile:

   ```
   # just after shebang
   exec 2>/path/to/logfile 1>&2
   ```

   This method will work even if `myscript` runs without a terminal.
2. Alternatively let the script run an interactive shell (e.g. `bash`) at the very end. The new shell will prevent the window from closing and you will be able to see what the script has printed to the terminal so far. This obviously requires a terminal. Note if `myscript` happens to `exit` or `kill` itself or `exec` to another executable then it will never get to the line with `bash`; take it into consideration.

   If for some reason the interactive `bash` started from the script clears the terminal or something, use `sleep 3600` instead. The point is you don't really need an extra shell, you need any process that keeps the terminal emulator open long enough so you can examine the previous output.

No matter which method you choose, place

```
set -x
```

early in `myscript` to make the shell interpreting it print commands and they arguments as they are executed. This should give you useful insight.